# pdksh time built-in function does not work

Tags: pdksh

```
$ time -p sleep 5
real 8.33
user 0.00
sys 0.00

$ /usr/bin/time -p sleep 5
real 5.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00

$ echo $KSH_VERSION
@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2
```

I have noticed this issue:
on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago).
and on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.8 (Tikanga).

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I have found the maintainer of a fork of pdksh that had the same problem. He has fixed the bug:[github.com/Orc/pdksh/commit/5d...](https://github.com/Orc/pdksh/commit/5dca20001ca3154fbc9159a8cb09a5072c375b96)

The symbol CLK_TCK has been removed from a C header by an evil standardisation commitee. As a result pdksh was using a default value (60) instead of the correct value that can be displayed using the following command:

```
$ getconf CLK_TCK
100
```

If you need a quick and dirty patch, you can either download the source of the rpm and fix the value in ksh_time.h or you can install the fork.